# ConfigurationManager to get project config data

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

I have created a config file within my project, and called it MyConfig.config.  It contains the following:

```
<configuration>
  <MySection MyString="StringHere"/>
</configuration>
```

I’’m trying to access this as follows:

```
AppSettingsSection settings = (AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection");
string myString = settings.Settings["MyString"].Value;
```

Clearly I’m doing something wrong.  Is it even possible to use the ConfigurationManager in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  There are a couple of steps.  First, you have to define your section in the config.  This involves declaring the section name and the type (class you have written):

```
<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="myConfig" type="MyConfig.MyConfigSectionHandler,MyConfig" />
   </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Next, you have to actually write the code to handle the section. It must inherit from IConfigurationSectionHandler:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyConfig
{
   public enum LevelSetting
   {
      High,
      Medium,
      Low,
      None
   }
   public class MyConfigSectionHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler
   {
      public virtual object Create(object parent,object configContext,XmlNode section)
      {
         int iLevel = 0;
         string sName = "";

         ConfigHelper.GetEnumValue(section, "level", typeof(LevelSetting), ref iLevel);
         ConfigHelper.GetStringValue(section,"name",ref sName);
         return new MyConfigSection((LevelSetting)iLevel,sName);
      }
   }
   public class MyConfigSection
   {
      private LevelSetting level = LevelSetting.None;
      private string name = null;

      public MyConfigSection(LevelSetting _level,string _name)
      {
         level = _level;
         name = _name;
      }
      public LevelSetting Level
      {
         get {return level;}
      }
      public string Name
      {
         get {return name;}
      }
   }
   internal class ConfigHelper
   {
      public static XmlNode GetEnumValue
      (XmlNode _node, string _attribute,Type _enumType, ref int _val)
      {
         XmlNode a = _node.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem(_attribute);
         if(a==null)
            throw new ConfigurationException("Attribute required: " + _attribute);
         if(Enum.IsDefined(_enumType, a.Value))
            _val = (int)Enum.Parse(_enumType,a.Value);
         else
            throw new ConfigurationException("Invalid Level",a);
         return a;
      }
      public static XmlNode GetStringValue(XmlNode _node, string _attribute, ref string _val)
      {
         XmlNode a = _node.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem(_attribute);
         if(a==null)
            throw new ConfigurationException("Attribute required: " + _attribute);
         else
            _val = a.Value;
         return a;      
      }
   }
}
```

Next, add the actual configuration item into the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <myConfig level="High" name="hello world" />
</system.web>
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Does you config file gets copied to the output directory and renamed to YourExeFile.exe.config? As far as i know you have to name your config file app.config or copy it by yourself after building.

When you want to load the config form an alternative config file you can use the `ConfigurationMangager.OpenMappedConfigurationFile()` method to load that file instead of the default config file. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration%28VS.80%29.aspx) for an example.

When you want to use a custom user defined config section, you have to provide classes to access that section. Take a look at [this good article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the config file in this way. Have you considered using a .settings file?